# cms для Блога

Tags: php, cms

Собственно, какой cms лучше для создания личного блога?

Необходимые возможности:

- Создавать статьи
- Теги для статей
- Комментарии к статьям
- Поиск по всем статьям

И еще немного:

- Компактный по объему
- Относительно быстрый

Comment: wordpress в помощь.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если задача быстро запустить блог — то [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/download/).

Если это вопрос по программированию — напишите свой блоговый движок по вводному уроку для фреймворка [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

Comment: сам фрейморк Yii достаточно громоздкий. 

кроме WordPress есть еще cms-ки для блога?

Comment: Готовое решение http://www.blogger.com (by Google)
Конечно и Joomla подойдет, но по мне слишком громоздкая и небезопасная.
Ну и конечно же лучше самому написать, если есть знания, время и нервы.

Comment: MaxSite еще есть, и на крайний случай Drupal - смотрите готовые сборки, их много на все случаи жизни )))
Можно попробовать самому сделать на CodeIgniter'e.

Comment: > сам фрейморк Yii достаточно громоздкий.

@ivsevolod: «вам скока вешать в граммах?» ) Нет, правда, Yii «достаточно» тяжёл, по-вашему, по памяти, файлам, или проц. грузит — в чём измеряете, и как?

WordPress с WPSuperCache весьма эффективен и быстр, "не надо недооценивать Силу" : )

Comment: Wordpress быстрый, простой по структуре, вагон плагинов и тем, просто допиливать и легко расширять.

Comment: @pshentsoff, плагинов то полно, но они слабо модерируются, а значит в этой куче плагинов полно незакрытых уязвимостей. В связи с популярностью вордпресса развелось полно спамеров, от которых все труднее и труднее защищаться.

@sergiks, что на счет тяжести, я имел в виду объема занимаемого на диске и кол-во файлов.

Comment: @IVsevolod,плагины практически ни у кого из фришных не модерирутся. Если так ставить вопрос тогда лучше платный, сервис, чтоб кто-то с головой и руками следил, ну или Drupal. И спамеры не только на вордпресс липнут и тут готовые решения не помогут, а лучше свое что-нибудь навешивать - так вернее от ботов отвязаться ибо боты на стандартные настроены: переабзови поля формы, спрячь в скрипт отправку - и все, процентов 99 ботов, распространяемых для кулхацкеров станут проходить мимо.

Answer (score 5):

Есть еще [Yupe](https://github.com/yupe/yupe). Она на yii.

Comment: опять же, для Юпи насколько мне известно нужен фреймворк YII, который достаточно громоздкий...

Comment: @IVsevolod 2 коммента и все от тебя что Yii громоздкий. Ты это про его размер в 20Мб? У тебя на хостинге лимит 10мб?

Или просто влом читать о нем? Я бы выбрал Yupe из-за того что он лучше WP однозначно. Но у меня есть свой блог на Yii, и сейас расширяется, причем достаточно быстро.

Comment: @IVsevolod мне вот тоже не совсем понятно по каким критериям он громоздкий.

Comment: на Yii я пишу на работе :) скорее в лом закачивать по фтп 20 Мб, и периодически его потом обновлять.

Comment: composer update? :)

Answer (score 5):

Если охота писать самому и Фреймворки не нравятся, пиши сам на "голом" PHP. Вот недели 2 назад начал сам, почти всё готово...